# How to get the date and time of a post?

Tags: php, date, time

I got this feedback form I made, and I would like to get the date and time, when a person posted a feedback, and display it next to their name. So, how can I get the date and time?

Here is the code for the form:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['add'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        if($name){
            if($email){
                if($comment){
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (id, name, email, comment) VALUES ('','$name','$email','$comment')");
                    //redirect
                    header("Location: mypage.php");
                }
                else
                    $msg = "You haven't entered any comment!";
            }
            else
                $msg = "You haven't entered an email address!";
        }
        else
            $msg = "You haven't entered your name!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: The easiest way would be using the UNIX timestamp. http://php.net/time

Comment: After calling `header('Location...')` be sure to place an `exit;` otherwise the rest of the script will executed.

Comment: @Tigger If there would be "a rest"

Comment: `mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (id, name, email, comment, when) VALUES ('','$name','$email','$comment',NOW())");`
                    `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the date and time at the point of the `$_POST` of your current system by using:

`$curDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

This would return the date/time in the following format: 2015-01-11 13:17:52 - Which you can then store in the database with your `INSERT INTO` query.

Make sure you have the correct timezone set within PHP as by default it may return UTC time. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Answer (score 0):

Don't change your PHP code, but change your database table: add a column named, say, `time`, of type TIMESTAMP with as default value CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

You don't need to change your PHP, the database will automatically put the current time in the new `time` column when you insert a new record.